# Installing git-flow on Ubuntu 10.10 fails silently

Tags: ubuntu-10.10, git-flow

I'm trying to install gitflow using the directions on the github [readme](http://github.com/nvie/gitflow) a la : wget -q -O - https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/raw/develop/contrib/gitflow-installer.sh | sudo sh

And it's failing silently...just back to the prompt.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hey, it is a problem with github certificate and wget

```
ERROR: certificate common name `*.github.com' doesn't match requested host name `github.com'.
To connect to github.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

just override wget checks

```
wget --no-check-certificate -q -O - https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/raw/develop/contrib/gitflow-installer.sh | sudo sh
```

works just fine ;)

Comment: it's a known issue, http://support.github.com/discussions/site/2230-wget-doesnt-like-the-ssl-certificate