# Gitflow Installation Problems

Tags: git, git-flow

I am trying to get gitflow running on Windows using the instructions here: https://github.com/nvie/gitflow (I am using Windows Server 2003 SP2 64 bit)

I have tried both Cygwin and msysgit.

With Cygwin, calling wget just returns nothing.

With msysgit I get quite a bit further, but when I try and run git flow init I get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git/libexec/git-core/git-flow: line 45: dirname: command not found
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git/libexec/git-core/git-flow: line 68: /gitflow-common: No such file or directory
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git/libexec/git-core/git-flow: line 76: /gitflow-shFlags: No such file or directory
```

Looking at the first error in the git-flow bash file, line 45 contains:

```
export GITFLOW_DIR=$(dirname "$0")
```

I've also tried following the steps here https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/issues/issue/25?authenticity_token=54d6387519b4751c2fb13840c52bb819dee10af4 but it doesn't make any difference.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: The `-q` option turns off `wget`'s output, so if you're following those instructions I wouldn't expect it to show anything, just silently fetch the file. Try it without that to see if it's succeeding and you didn't realize it, or if there's an error.

Comment: Thanks after removing -q I could see I was getting a certificate error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the msysgit installation, I'm not sure where dirname would normally come from (I'm not a windows guy). It's possible it's included in that util-linux package that is mentioned in the gitflow installation instructions. It's also possible your PATH is borked - have a look in the usual places (/bin, /usr/bin, /usr/local/bin) and see if dirname is in any of them, and see if your PATH is missing that one. Failing all that, `dirname $0` is simply the name of the directory containing that script, so it's possible that you could simply hardcode that and proceed.

Edit:

Aha. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317498/installing-git-flow-on-ubuntu-10-10-fails-silently), the wget certificate error is a known issue, not specific to github. It's been fixed in wget, but the fix hasn't been released yet in debian/ubuntu, and I'm not sure how long it'll take to work its way through to cygwin. You can work around it as mentioned in the linked question, though. But of course, I think it's probably much better to use msysgit than cygwin git, from what I've heard.

Comment: Thanks, in the end I changed the script to have the directory name hardcoded.

Comment: I have edited msysgit-install.cmd and find this: xcopy "%~dp0\..\shFlags\src\shflags"  changing this path or creating this folders structure and putting gitflow-shflags file into it is a solution.

Answer (score 5):

This is how I got it to work in Windows:

1. Install msysgit: http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/
2. Follow the install instructions in the gitflow readme: https://github.com/nvie/gitflow
3. Download "git-flow-completion": https://github.com/bobthecow/git-flow-completion

   - Copy "git-flow-completion.bash" from the git-flow-completion zip file to C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\etc
   - Create a new file called "bash_profile" (no extension) in C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\etc and add this one line:
     `source "c:\Program Files (x86)\Git\etc\git-flow-completion.bash"`

Comment: In case anyone else gets the same issue I had, I had to manually download (or clone via Git) the [shFlags](https://github.com/nvie/shFlags) content into the root of the cloned GitFlow folder, so that running the command file performed all file copying correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the path returned by the "export GITFLOW_DIR=$(dirname "$0")".

Solution: https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/pull/161

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem happening with my machine was that the git flow install was adding the flow files to the

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\libexec\git-core
```

but the **git flow init** was looking for them in the

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\libexec\
```

so I just copied and pasted them in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\libexec\
```

Now it works!